# Android Tablet Resource Qualifiers Not Working As Expected

Tags: android, android-resources

In order to support large tablets,  I'm using 2 separate drawable folders:

```
drawable-w720dp-mdpi
drawable-w720dp-xhdpi
```

I'm using a 10" mdpi tablet to test.

Now according to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) I would have expected it to use the `drawable-w720dp-mdpi` folder, but this is not the case.  It seems the device always uses the highest DPI qualifier available.  So if I have:

```
drawable-w720dp-xhdpi
drawable-w720dp-xxhdi
```

It will use the xxhdpi one.

To test this I'm using:

```
// Gives 1.0 (mdpi)
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 

TypedValue returnedValue = new TypedValue();
getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.test, returnedValue);
// returnedValue.string gives me the path to the resource in use
```

And the resource in present in both folders

*It seems this problem only occurs with tablets* - 
My phone uses the correct resources when configured this way

**MORE INFO**
It seems that it works correctly on the tablet using `xlarge` instead of `w720dp` as a qualifier.

The tablet I'm testing on is a Sanei N10

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it work.

```
drawable-sw720dp-mdpi
drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi
```